# Quasi Monte Carlo: Is not grid search the ultimate low discrepancy sequence?

Tags: monte-carlo, quasi-monte-carlo

I realize that subsequences won't be low discrepancy, but if I know how many samples I want and that I am operating on the unit hypercube, why not just grid search as the low discrepancy sequence in quasi Monte Carlo methods?

Like... grid search is in some sense going to be the *lowest* discrepancy sequence I could use given number of points *N*.

- Am I correct that grid search in discrepancy minimizing?
- Do fancier sequences, e.g. Sobol, have some properties other than low discrepancy that make them better?
- If I do this it's just the rectangle method for integration. Does QMC with better sequences beat the rectangle method?

*By grid search I mean partitioning the unit hypercube into equal size cubes and then iterating over vertices